# divide complex finction in to multiple linear functions

Tags: linearization

im programing a small controler an have to use sqrt but the controler doesnt suport it  . the controler have what they call a 24 point linearization wich means that you chose 24 x and y positions and the controler makes 23 linear functions out of it.

My cucuestion is how do i find the optimal points for the function

Y= sqrt(x)  from 0 to 7, first point is x=0 and last X=7

could it be done in excel?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please edit your answer to add what you tried and take the opportunity to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and to correct some typos.

Comment: Define "optimal".